# Bootstrap datatable not working on adding accordion

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, html-table, accordion

I have a datatable as follows:

```
foreach($tickets as $tickets)
{
    echo ('<tr>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->error.'</td>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->hours.'</td>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->time.'</td>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->date.'</td>');
    echo ('</tr>');
}
```

I added accordion effect to it likewise:

```
foreach($tickets as $tickets)
{
    echo ('<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo1">');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->error.'</td>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->hours.'</td>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->time.'</td>');
    echo ('<td>'.$tickets->date.'</td>');
    echo ('</tr>');
    echo ('<tr>');
    echo ('<td class="hiddenRow">');
    echo ('<div class="collapse demo1">Demo1</div>');
    echo ('</td>');
    echo ('</tr>');
}
```

and the table has lost it's datatable properties such as search, view as 10/25/50 items per page etc.

[image]

Jquery:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});

$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

I'd like help regarding this issue.

Comment: Do you see any console error?

Comment: check the script files  you might miss some script files to include

Comment: did you added this script file?  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  in my case  after addign this it started working pagination and search

Comment: @KK I have some console error, here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/IJ49iWe.png The error is in vendor.js file!

Comment: Here is the line in vendor.js throwing the error: https://i.imgur.com/wkCY8Nf.png

Comment: @user3663 Yes I already have included the jquery file in the head.

Comment: ok did you write script for your table id like this? <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>

Comment: can you create fiddle of your code?

Comment: @BhumiShah I'm not able to make it work on jsfiddle for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/3ghbLrpu/

This is the effect I'm trying to recreate: http://jsfiddle.net/QLfMU/

Answer (score 0):

Try using colspan="4" on the second td

Comment: That did not fix it, it simply centered the data that was displayed on expanding the accordion

Comment: do you have <tbody> and <thead> tags?

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ghbLrpu/1/

```
<html>

  <head>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Error</th>
          <th>Time Spent</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Error</th>
          <th>Time Spent</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
          <td>asd</td>
          <td>asd</td>
          <td>asd</td>
          <td>asd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="4">
            <div class="collapse demo1">Demo1</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
```

**CSS**

```
.hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

***Another option is use bootstrap and remove knockoutjs***

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/XYMRyQ

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#collapseme").click(function() {
    if($("#test").hasClass("out")) {
        $("#test").addClass("in");
        $("#test").removeClass("out");
    } else {
        $("#test").addClass("out");
        $("#test").removeClass("in");
    }
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Error</th>
          <th>Time Spent</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="" id="collapseme">
          <td>asd</td>
          <td>asd</td>
          <td>asd</td>
          <td>asd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="4">
            <div class="collapse out" id="test">Demo1</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Error</th>
          <th>Time Spent</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: How is this different from my fiddle except for the inclusion of the jquery files in head and the class 'accordion-toggle'? I made these changes and I still have the same problem. I still get  'type error s is undefined in vendor.js file too.

Comment: Yes, included required js, accordion-toggle class and colspan="4"

Comment: Hmm, nope.. https://i.imgur.com/IFycmul.gifv I added a few more columns just now btw.

Comment: so it is not related to this. may be s is undefined error occuring due to something else and it is not affecting you toggle, is workign

Comment: Yes but this problem occurs only when adding the accordion effect. Are there any alternate implementation of the accordion effect which I can try out?

Comment: added anothero option to try out!!